# How to design log structure for a Java application

Tags: java, multithreading

Am new to java, I know Java has Log4J, logback etc for logging purposes. My question is more around how many log files should we have in a application. Should it be per thread, per group of threads, process, exception etc. In our application there is a possibility of having a large number of threads and am thinking about cons of having log file per thread. Are there best practices for logging in applications having huge number of threads .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you log in the first place??

Answer (score 3):

1 log for messages - Call it SystemOut.log

1 log for stack traces - Call it SystemErr.log

1 log for traces -  Call it Trace.log

1 log for native stdout - Call it nativeStdOut.log

1 log for native stderr - Call it nativeStdErr.log

Have a config panel that sets:

```
 maxSize
 maxCount
```

When a log hits max size, starting rolling them upto maxCount and append a timestamp to the rolled filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think that good solution would be to name your threads and write logs together with the name of thread in which log occurred. Thanks to that you will be able to both analysis logs separately for each thread or analysis all logs together.

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is one log file per application (process) -- rarely for `Thread` and never be `Exception`.  Sometimes this log file is split into various different log levels: debug messages in one bucket, information in another, warnings/errors in a third.  This makes it easy to watch for errors by only looking at the warning-and-more-critical file.

log4j has a configuration file in which you can route certain messages to certain files using different criteria.  Here's a sample of the log4j properties file:

```
# default is WARN and above going to the appender "logfile" and STDOUT
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, logfile, stdout
# write to ui.log for a day and then move to .yyyy-MM-dd suffix
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=ui.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
# but we log information message from classes in the package com.mprew.be
log4j.logger.com.mprew.be=INFO
```

log4j, and custom loggers, decorate each time with a `Class` name, priority level, date/time, etc..   For example:

```
# date     time        priority  Class-name  Log message
2012-03-26 00:55:39,545 [INFO] CmsClientTask Content is up-to-date
```

Typically exceptions are written out as multiple lines so you can get the entire stack-trace.

```
2012-03-26 01:55:35,777 [INFO] ExceptionInterceptor Reporting problem to customer
    org.springframework.NoSuchRequestException: No request handling method
     at com.ui.base.BaseController.invokeNamedHandler(BaseController.java:240)
     at com.ui.base.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:100)
     at com.ui.base.CoreServices.handleRequest(CoreServicesController.java:147)
     ...
```

In our distributed system, we route all logs from all of the system to 2 servers which write a debug, info, and warning logs.  Along with the date/time, class name, priority, and message, the log messages also have the hostname and a specific log token so we can easily identify classes of problems.  The following is on one line:

```
2012-03-26 00:00:00.045 UTC INFO FE8 TrayController TRAY_CLIENT_LOOKUP
    message=created unknown client with partner STW9
```

Then we can easily grep for specific issues.

Hope this helps.